# Keep Access Settings From Original Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Master Spreadsheet that contains a sheet that is both hidden and locked. Thus, users with comment rights to the Spreadsheet cannot access the hidden sheet.

However, once a user makes a copy of the Master Spreadsheet they are then able to view and edit the information in the hidden sheet (Note that I do want users to be able to make a copy of the Spreadsheet).

Is there a way to keep the hidden sheet locked in all copies of the Master Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, in Google Sheets there is no way to keep the hidden sheet locked in all copies of the Master Spreadsheet.

best you can do is to set font color to white on those hidden sheets :)

if those hidden sheets contain some formulas (or secrets) which you do not want to share then export them into a separate spreadsheet and then use `IMPORTRANGE` in your shared master sheet

Comment: by using IMPORTRANGE, I imagine the data will still be available in the copied Spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm thinking to build a macro that triggers when the copied spreadsheet is opened (is a copy considered an open event?), and the macro will implement the protection permissions on the copied Spreadsheet. Please let me know if you have any insights on this approach.

Comment: yes, visible data will still be available (this excludes formulas)